# Pass a variable from command line into scenario or feature in feature file

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, python-behave

Currently I have Behave tests that run in Selenium but pick which browser to test based on an Environment Variable. Is there any way to pass text from the command line to a `.feature` file?

Something like:

`DRIVER=chrome behave /path/to/features -i test -D browser=chrome`

And then in the `test.feature` file be able to do something like this:

```
Feature: Testing something in "{browser}"

  @browser
  Scenario: Something can do something in "{browser}"
    Given I am on "index"
    ...
```

This would prevent allure reports from considering these the same text or having to write the tests once for each browser. I did figure out how to do tags like this but it didn't cause allure to treat them any differently so the most recent browser is the only version of the test that shows up.

Comment: Part of this is now possible if you use Scenario Outlines and Examples. See http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#name-may-contain-placeholders
still can't find a way for Feature description.]

Comment: Also noting it doesn't answer the general question but my example use case may solved by https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/130 when it gets released.